# What different between New and Object and how it work in stack and heap

Tags: c#, object

When I code as below, it will create an address at our stack and heap.

```
Student student = new Student();
```

and when I create an object it also create an address at our stack. At the same time it will need more space on the RAM cause you need read it out. So why we still want use below this?

```
int x=0;
object student=x
int y=(int)student
```

Comment: What is your question by the way? The examples you have provided are of 1. Creating an instance of an object and 2. Boxing/Unboxing

Comment: These aren't equivalent as far as I can tell. Even if a `Student` is an abstraction around an `int`, it's not the same as *naming* an object ref `student` and assigning it an `int`.

Comment: For a start your second block of code wouldn't even compile. Secondly, the 2 snippets are not remotely similar, certainly not enough to compare them. It's like asking "What is the difference between a sandwich and Tuesday?"

Comment: You don't need that.  But boxing implements the type system illusion that all value types in .NET inherit from System.Object.  It is quite a useful illusion.  Java has it as well but they fumbled it pretty badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're very confused on a lot of things. `new` and `object` are hardly even in the same realm. Let me explain:

**A. "When I code as below, it will create an address at our stack and heap"**

Not true. If `Student` is a class (it usually would be) it would go in the heap. If it was a struct, however, it will go on the stack. That's the main difference between the struct and class.

**B. `object` isn't used to create anything, at least not in the way `new` does.**

`object` is a *type*. Everything can be implicitly casted to `object` because everything inherits from it. When you cast a value type to `object`, you're converting it from a value type to a reference type, therefore it has to be "boxed" as a reference, and "unboxed" when you cast from object back to a value type.

You can just as easily be doing this:

```
int x = 0;
int y = x;
```

**C. `new` calls the constructor of the type you are creating, `object` does not. If we had:**

```
public class Student
{
    public Student() => Console.WriteLine("Student Enrolled");
}

...

var student1 = new Student();
Student student2;
```

This would print `"Student Enrolled"`, but only once, because `student2` never called `new Student()`. If I did `object student3 = new Student();`, this will print, but only because `student` is still calling `new`, nothing to do with `object` being involved at all.

**D. `[object]x` is invalid C# syntax``

I'm not sure if you come from a different programming language, but in C/C++/C#, casting is done using `()` braces, not `[]` braces, so it should be `int y = (int)object`.

The `[]` braces are used for indexing.

**E. When we would want to us `object` to box/unbox**

Boxing/unboxing is what you are doing in your second example, casting an `int` to `object` and back. That is a pattern that was more common in the days before generics. If I wanted a list of items that could be used for any type, I could use an `object[]`.

Problem is, they can put any type they want in there. They could put an `int`, `string[]`, `Guid`, `Student`, etc, all in the same array, and they'll have to cast/unbox, everytime to the value they wanted, which wasn't good for performance. Now, with generics though, we can just do `List<int>` and this collection will only allow `int`s, and it won't box them or make me cast to get the `int` back.

One way I used it recently though, is when dealing with `enum`s. Doing something so that the user can cast from one `enum` to another, using generics.

If I did:

```
public TEnumTo CastToU<TEnumFrom, TEnumTo>(TEnumFrom enumFrom) 
    where TEnumFrom : System.Enum 
    where TEnumTo   : System.Enum 
{
    return (TEnumTo)enumFrom;
}
```

It would give an error, even though we can cast from any given `enum` to another, normally, even though it knows both types are `enum`s.

So what I had to do was this:

```
public TEnumTo CastToU<TEnumFrom, TEnumTo>(TEnumFrom enumFrom) 
    where TEnumFrom : System.Enum 
    where TEnumTo   : System.Enum 
{
    return (TEnumTo)(object)enumFrom;
}
```

This works because any variable can be casted to `object` and from `object` I can cast to any other variable.

Comment: `var student2` is no bueno tho and `object student3` would just delay the problem if not assigned before use; same as `Object student3`.

Comment: Right about the `var`, forgot. And of course you eventually will have to use `new`, (unless using some assignment or method return value) using `object` won't change that.

Comment: @AustinWBryan thanks a lot. u was explained very clearly.  learn a lot of things from your comments. appreciations.